# Select Vertices by Material Color

Tags: selection-tools

I have a mesh in .obj fileformat which if I render in color looks like this:

[image: Mesh Color Example]

I would like to select only the brown/dark colored parts and delete the rest. How can I achieve this ? Is there a select vertices by material color ? Or can I do this differently ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working a obj you created from a  photogrammetry ?
IF so, you cannot. Unless you wanted to do that in an earlier part of the process... Photogrammetry takes the mesh and attaches the texture to the entire mesh. So you cannot separate out the texture by color because they are all on the same texture file... you can split up the faces and then assign them a new texture then delete that texture but at that point you're not avoiding the problem of having to delete everything.

When working with Photo scans you just have to except the fact that you will have to do some busy work. There are programs that can auto fix your typology - which may help in selecting methods ( being able to select and delete edge loops), but other than that you will be working at the geometry level which does not see color-only textures hold that data.

This is a really late reply. However, if anyone sees this I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could select the material slot and then click 'Select', which will select the faces that have this material. Only faces have material assigned, vertices don't.

You can do this in Edit mode only with thanks to Delagone :)

[image]

Comment: I'd add that this is only possible in 'Edit Mode'

Comment: Thats great. Thanks for showing me this. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem because it selects all the material and not just the brow/black parts. I don't know enough about how Blender stores this information, but somewhere the color must be associated with a vertice and I am wondering if I can tap into that so I can select a certain color range and discard the rest. This would really be helpful for me. Thanks again.